# DIY Syringe Lubricant

Tags: water-pressure

I made a syringe (used for a pressure system) myself, it seems to have a tight fit around the cylinder. 
I used non-waterproof clay coated by hot glue (to make it waterproof), and the problem is that the layer of hot glue has too much friction. 
So I guess I'll have to use a lubricant to reduce the friction, but not sure what to use. 
Some of my teachers recommended some type of oil, like olive oil or butter. 
Which one will work better - liquid oil or butter? 

The syringe will have water in it so the butter would probably be in the solid state. 
Would oil contaminate into the water? I'm really not sure what to use, please help!

Comment: What material is the syringe moving?  Water?  If so, what is its use?  That is to determine if it would matter if the fluid is slightly "contaminated" with butter or oil?  Is it to deliver sterile water into a medical patient?  Or is it used as a hydraulic medium to lift a vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a product known as plumbers grease, used for faucets and other plumbing applications. The water from those faucets is used for drinking and cooking and other household applications. The grease is also known as PTFE lubricant, also known as teflon compound.

A liquid oil would not have much staying power and may react with the walls of the syringe. Butter would eventually turn rancid as would other organic compounds.

Teflon is known for lack of reactivity as well as durability under high pressure and temperature, although it's unlikely you'd be dealing with either.

A thin film of teflon/PTFE/plumbing grease would provide a substantial reduction in friction with minimal contamination and also give you good duration of use. You would also want to consider if the hot glue you used is water resistant. Some products of that nature will slowly degrade when exposed to water.

All of the above is my opinion, backed up with some real world use and online research independent of this question.

Comment: I'll only be using the pressure system for couple of hours (it's for a lab), so would butter stay in its form during that time period?

Comment: I really can't advise how suitable is butter for lubrication. It's quite tasty when used on various foods, including popcorn and toasted bread, but as a lubricant, it's a tough call.  You would have little to lose by trying, as if it proved unsuitable for lubrication, it would wash off easily with soap and water. If there is enough movement in your syringe, it may wash off in that water.

Comment: I just tested it with butter, and it worked! thank you